# Customizing the Native Tag Meta Box

Tags: php, wordpress, tags, wordpress-theming

I've added a tag meta box and taxonomy to allow tags on my CPTs. However I cannot find the argument in the codex to edit "Separate tags with commas" and "Choose from the most used tags". Does anyone know of a filter or register_taxonomy argument for these?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a list of arguments for [get_taxonomy_labels](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_taxonomy_labels) which had the proper arguments for these fields. I was able to add these to my existing register_taxonomy() function's labels.

```
register_taxonomy( 'domain_tag', 
    array('domain_profiles'), /* if you change the name of register_post_type( 'domain_profiles', then you have to change this */
    array('hierarchical' => false,    /* if this is false, it acts like tags */
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __( 'Related Domains', 'bonestheme' ), /* name of the custom taxonomy */
            'singular_name' => __( 'Domain', 'bonestheme' ), /* single taxonomy name */
            'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Domains', 'bonestheme' ), /* search title for taxomony */
            'all_items' => __( 'All Related Domains', 'bonestheme' ), /* all title for taxonomies */
            'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Domain', 'bonestheme' ), /* parent title for taxonomy */
            'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Domain:', 'bonestheme' ), /* parent taxonomy title */
            'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Domain', 'bonestheme' ), /* edit Domain taxonomy title */
            'update_item' => __( 'Update Domain', 'bonestheme' ), /* update title for taxonomy */
            'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Domain', 'bonestheme' ), /* add new title for taxonomy */
            'new_item_name' => __( 'New Domain Name', 'bonestheme' ), /* name title for taxonomy */
            // See get_taxonomy_labels for more arguments (below)
            'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate domains with commas', 'bonestheme' ),
            'choose_from_most_used' => __( 'Choose from the most used', 'bonestheme' ),
        ),
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
    )
);
```